# delegate of iOS paired device reconnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have an application which is using `retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices` to get the list of paired `HID devices`. I can get the list and connect to the desired one successfully using `connectPeripheral` code. When the connection succeeds, following delegate is being called:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
```

and for disconnection, I get the corresponded delegate:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDisconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral error:(NSError *)error
```

Now when the `HID device` gets connected again to the iOS (**directly from Setting, not from my application**), I want to be informed. Is there any way to find out when an `HID device` reconnected to the OS?

Comment: Simply initiate a new connection in `didDisconnectPeripheral`. When the peripheral is back in range your connection will complete

Comment: @Paulw11 Is it guaranteed? I mean, do I get the connection surely by this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer.

Thanks to @Paulw11 for his guidance, based on [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html):

> When the user leaves home, the iOS device may eventually become out of range of the lock, causing the connection to the lock to be lost. At this point, the app can simply call the *connectPeripheral:options:* method of the *CBCentralManager* class, and because connection requests do not time out, the iOS device will reconnect when the user returns home.